# Javascript eval ReferenceError: is not defined

Tags: javascript, eval, referenceerror

I need to dynamical create a variable off the value of a variable from an argument I am pulling in from a script. But I first want to check if it already exists so I don't overwrite it, if it is already set.

I am leveraging eval to expand the value of the variable and tag it onto a variable suffix but no matter what I use to check for the undefined I am getting a reference error on the check.

Below is the simple code snippet

```
chkUser = args[1];

if(typeof eval(chkUser+"lastseen")==="undefined") ;
```

I've also tried put the eval in parens and putting undefined in ' ' and pulled them completely and switching typeof to the JavaScript standard undefined as such

```
if( eval(chkUser+"lastseen")=== undefined) ;
```

but I always get ReferenceError: robertlastseen is not defined or what ever chkUser expands out to.

Comment: Run the `typeof` call *inside* the `eval()`.  `if(eval('typeof '+chkUser+'lastseen') === "undefined")`

Comment: Have you considered storing these as properties of an `Object` rather than as separate variables? [Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) is usually simpler than `eval()` and won't throw ReferenceErrors. Or, pass a user object rather than the variable prefix as `args[1]` -- `if (typeof args[1].lastseen === 'undefined')`.

Comment: `I need to dynamical create a variable off the value of a variable` - Why?

Comment: `if (window[args[1]+"lastseen"])  ...`

Answer (score 2):

Its just a guess, but it seems like the Variable is just not defined before you eval it.

try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uxmvm/).

It works fine for me.

Try to hard-code the variable before you eval it like this:

```
chkUser = args[1];
var robertlastseen = 'Hardcode';
console.log(eval(chkUser+"lastseen"));
```

Then you should be able to debug your code.

if you just want to test if this Variable is declared try this:

```
if(eval('typeof ' + chkUser + 'lastseen') === "undefined"){
    //Variable undefined
}
```

Comment: That is correct nor should it if never seen it before thus the check for undefined so can take action based on having not seen the user before.